# How to change const variable to variable in class property?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class name GetCampaigns. It contains private const CUSTOMER_ID as a class property. I want to assign global variable value to this property.

GetCampaigns.php

```
class GetCampaigns
{
    private const CUSTOMER_ID = 1234567890; //$_COOKIE['customer_id']; //get_client_google_ads_customer_id($con, $_COOKIE['client_id']); 

    
    public static function main()
    {
        // Either pass the required parameters for this example on the command line, or insert them
        // into the constants above.
        $options = (new ArgumentParser())->parseCommandArguments([
            ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID => GetOpt::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT
        ]);

        // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
        
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile(__DIR__.'\google_ads_php.ini')->build();

        
        // Construct a Google Ads client configured from a properties file and the
        // OAuth2 credentials above.
        $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
            ->fromFile()
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            // We set this value to true to show how to use GAPIC v2 source code. You can remove the
            // below line if you wish to use the old-style source code. Note that in that case, you
            // probably need to modify some parts of the code below to make it work.
            // For more information, see
            // https://developers.devsite.corp.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/php/gapic.
            ->usingGapicV2Source(true)
            ->build();

        try {
            $data = self::runExample(
                $googleAdsClient, 
                $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: self::CUSTOMER_ID
            );

            return $data;
        } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
            printf(
                "Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
                $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
                PHP_EOL,
                PHP_EOL
            );
            foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
                /** @var GoogleAdsError $error */
                printf(
                    "\t%s: %s%s",
                    $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
                    $error->getMessage(),
                    PHP_EOL
                );
            }
            exit(1);
        } catch (ApiException $apiException) {
            printf(
                "ApiException was thrown with message '%s'.%s",
                $apiException->getMessage(),
                PHP_EOL
            );
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the example.
     *
     * @param GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient the Google Ads API client
     * @param int $customerId the customer ID
     */
    // [START get_campaigns]
    public static function runExample(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId)
    {
        $googleAdsServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient();
        // Creates a query that retrieves all campaigns.
        $query = 'SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name, metrics.impressions, metrics.clicks, metrics.conversions, metrics.ctr, metrics.average_cpc, metrics.cost_micros, campaign.bidding_strategy_type FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id';

        //  WHERE campaign.status = "ENABLED" 

        // Issues a search stream request.
        /** @var GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator $stream */
        $stream = $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream(
            SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest::build($customerId, $query)
        );

        $campaign_details_array = array();

        // Iterates over all rows in all messages and prints the requested field values for
        // the campaign in each row.
        foreach ($stream->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
            /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */


            $campaign_details_array[] = array('campaign_id' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getId(), 
                'campaign_name' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getName(),
                'impressions' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getImpressions(),
                'clicks' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getClicks(),
                'conversions' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getConversions(),
                'ctr' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCtr(),
                'average_cpc' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getAverageCpc(),
                'cost_micros' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCostMicros(),
                'bidding_strategy_type' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getBiddingStrategyType(),
            );
        }

        // print_r($campaign_details_array);
        return $campaign_details_array;
    }
    // [END get_campaigns]


}

GetCampaigns::main();
```

I have tried to change this following line to make customer_id dynamic

```
private const CUSTOMER_ID = 1234567890; //$_COOKIE['customer_id'];
```

to

```
private $customer_id = $_COOKIE['customer_id'];
```

and

```
try {
            $data = self::runExample(
                $googleAdsClient, 
                $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: self::CUSTOMER_ID
            );

            return $data;
        }
```

to

```
try {
            $data = self::runExample(
                $googleAdsClient, 
                $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: $this->customer_id
            );

            return $data;
        }
```

But this shows an error like

```
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\google-ads-php\GetCampaigns.php on line 42
```

Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is line no. 42 this line `private $customer_id = $_COOKIE['customer_id'];` ?

Comment: Yes @nice_dev. That's the 42nd line.

Comment: you are trying to introduce new hidden dependency to global variable, you should not do that, instead pass the value as parameter to your class, either to method main (since that is the only place i see it is used in your code) or constructor, or because $_COOKIE is global variable you can simply set class property inside constructor directly (hidden dependency warning), not having to use parameter. constants are actually static (once per class not instance) and can only be initialized from constant expression, so you must be able to deduce what value exactly would evaluate from source only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this. You can pass customer id as a parameter to main() method. Like this

```
public static main($customer_id)
```

and in try block use parameter

```
try {
            $data = self::runExample(
                $googleAdsClient, 
                $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: $customer_id
            );

            return $data;
        }
```

And when you call a function assign customer id value in a parameter

```
GetCampaigns::main($_COOKIE['customer_id']);
```